# Javascript, how to disable mousewheel click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable mousewheel click on link, but I don't know why it doesn't work. 
Here is my code :

html :

```
<a class="disable_mousewheel_event" href="https://code.jquery.com/">Click</a>
```

javascript :

```
$(function() {
    $(".disable_mousewheel_event").on("mouseup", function(event) {
        if (event.which == 2) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: The tab opening does not happen on `mouseup`. It happens on `mousedown`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent  'mouseup' would be related to a button press.  Checkout the wheel events.

Comment: I already try  "return false" and "mousedown". Doesn't work.

Comment: Disabling a middle click is almost always the wrong approach. Are you also going to disable `ctrl+click`? You can't stop someone from opening the link in a new tab if they really want to.

Comment: @zzzzBox He did actually the same and his example doesn't work, however you marked it as duplicated. Gj man :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is("a[href]") && e.button === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://code.jquery.com/">Click</a>
```